# is it possible to open a spreadsheet in excel from silverlight

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have created a spreadsheet from a grid in silverlight, but as silverlight runs in a sandbox, it's not possible to open the spreadsheet directly from the application. I can open an OpenFileDialog and select the file, then read it into a FileStream. However, I am unable to open it in Excel from my silverlight application.

```
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            FileInfo sheet = openFileDialog.File;
            if (sheet.Extension == ".xlsx")
            {
                FileStream stream = sheet.OpenRead();

                // I need to either stream it to excel somehow 
                // or open it without the stream. 
            }
        }
```

Does anyone know how to do this or even if it's possible to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Lee

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/66089029-b479-4f0e-88f9-42e2d6890559/how-to-launch-an-excel-from-silvelight-application

Comment: That's where the code is from, but it doesn't tell me how to call Excel and stream the FileSream to it.